# Java Bucket Sort

Tags: java

I am trying to create my own style of Bucket Sort and I am getting an error with my code and I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be great. I have two classes, Node and BucketSort:

```
public class Node {

    protected int element;
    protected Node next;

    public Node()
    {
        element = 0;
        next = null;
    }
    public Node getNext(Node n)
    {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(Node n)
    {
        n = next;
    }
    public void setElement(int e)
    {
        e = element;
    }
    public int getElement()
    {
        return element;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class BucketSort extends Node{


    public static void bucketSort(int v, int[] b) //b = the array of integers and v = number of buckets wanted. 
    {
        Node[] bucket = new Node[v];  //Creating an array of type Node called bucket with v buckets. 
        for (int i=0; i<=b.length; i++){
            bucket[i].setElement(b[i]);   //Loop through array of integers b, and set each element to the corresponding index of array bucket.
        return;
        }

        for (int i=0; i<=bucket.length; i++){
             //Getting the element at the indexed Node of array "bucket" and assigning it to the array "b" at location element-1. For example if the element is 3, then 3 is assigned to index 2, since it is the 3rd spot.
            b[getElement()-1] = bucket[i].getElement(); 
            return; 
        }
        System.out.println(b);
    }

}
```

I am getting the following Error at line 16 of BucketSort, the is code: b[getElement()-1]

The Error is:

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getElement() from the type Node.

Can you please tell me how to fix this.

Thanks

How can I Test This Program?

Comment: In its current form, this is not even a question. Why did you delete all the info?

Comment: I rollbacked it. @Brian: please don't break questions.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your misuse of the `static` keyword. I'm not sure if you're familiar with the semantics of static methods in Java (if you're not, you should read something comprehensive about it, maybe [starting here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)), but the basic idea is that a method or field that is declared `static` belongs to the *class* and not any particular instance (object) of that class. In particular, `static` methods don't have any notion of a `this` pointer.

So the problem is that when your code calls `getElement()` by itself, Java is implicitly interpreting that as `this.getElement()`. However, `bucketSort()` is `static` while `getElement()` belongs to an instance of `Node`, so this doesn't make any sense -- what exactly is `getElement()` being called on?

Call it on a particular `Node` object, like `bucket[i]`, and it'll compile (haven't really seen if it'll work though).

Comment: That would resolve that compiler error, but I don't think it's a good "Big-Picture" thing to do. For one, it would mean you would have to first create a BucketSort object before you could call the actual sorting method. The root of your problem is that BucketSort subclasses Node, which is weird. Re-design that and the proper patterns should fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

See the error. It tells the mistake you have done.

You can call the `getElement()` for a particular object.

And why `bucketSort(int v, int[] b)` need to be static? Any reasons?